# Live Server Extension's Default Browser Problem

Tags: visual-studio-code, settings, liveserver

I use Brave browser as my default browser but don't want to use it in developing purpose while I am in VS Code and therefore I use Live server extension and I changed the extension's default browser as chrome but it didn't worked while I am in remote WSL Ubuntu environment.

Need some assist in it, that how can I use chrome as Live server default browser while I am working in remote WSL Ubuntu environment without changing my Windows default browser settings.

I use Google chrome Dev not actual Chrome.

Comment: I didn't know that you can change the browser in `live server` extension.
That feature is in live server ++ .

Answer (score 1):

Start live share, then copy the live server link at the top of brave (should be like http://127.0.0.1:5500/your-file.html) and then paste in chrome.

Comment: Really I appreciate the solution cause I am using the same way currently. But I need to know why the default browser settings in Live server extension doesn't work in WSL Ubuntu remote environment.